# Recursively call system while mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I've been trying for a while to mock my codes. I'm newby on mocking so lots of things ahead of me to catch. I'm using Powermockito with Mockito and Easymock integration.

**I'm having difficulties with mocking a method which is inside the method I wanted to test.** So here is an example of the situation I faced:

```
public class trialClass {
 public static int try2(){    
        return 3;    
    }

    public static int try(int a){    
        return try2() + a;    
    }
}
```

and my test class is:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(trial.class)
public class trialTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {    
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(trial.class);    

        //Here I expect try2() to return 10, even it return 3
        PowerMockito.when(trial.try2()).thenReturn(10);    
    }

    @Test
    public void testtry() throws Exception {
        //After try2() returns 10 recursively inside my try() method,
        //I expect result to be 11
        Assert.assertEquals(11, trial.try(1));    
    }
}
```

**This question of mine actually comes from my session variable. My session holds some value and an X method returns that value. All I need is to mock that X method recursively and this question just simulates this case.**

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Java naming: **Class Names Start With Capitals**!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS`

So in your test setup:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(trial.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

Comment: That worked just fine. Thanks. But, does it cause any real-time data changes? I've heard something like that before.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

It occurred to me that you might not want to change to EasyMock instead of Mockito, in that case please disregard...

Partial mocking is the keyword you are after. You don't want to mock everything, just `try2()`. You should use the [PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Class, String...)](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.1/apidocs/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.html#mockStaticPartial%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29) method.

Instead of

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(trialClass.class);
```

Use

```
PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(trialClass.class, "try2");
```

And then do the actual mocking.

Also note that you defined the clas as `trialClass` in the code above, but use `trial.class` in the second code...

Comment: The problem here is, I don't use Powermock, that's why mockStaticPartial method was not found in this case. How it will effect the confuguration of my current mocking and unit testing structure if I include it to my project scope?

Answer (score 0):

Please find an updated version of your *TrialTest.java* using EasyMock with PowerMock as a solution. PowerMock is easy to configure and does not interfere with most existing jars. You only need a few JARS

- powermock-easymock-X.X.X-full.jar
- Easymock-X.X.jar

You had some issues with your code that I fixed:

- Code Issue: *try* is a Java keyword so it cannot be used in method name (e.g., *try(int a)*).
- Code Quality: Use Java Object instead of Java primitive (e.g., Use Integer instead of int).
- Code Quality: *trialClass* is a poor Java class name (e.g., Use upperCase for Java class name, don't use the generic word Class unless for educational purposes), maybe Trial.

Here's the updated code:

**Trial.java (CUT)**

```
public class Trial {

    public static Integer try2() {
        return 3;
    }

    public static Integer try1(int a) {
        return try2() + a;
    }
}
```

Working Test Class: **TrialTest.java**

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Trial.class)
public class TrialTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        /* Setup */
        PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Trial.class, "try2");

        /* Mocks */
        // Here I expect try2() to return 10, even it return 3
        EasyMock.expect(Trial.try2()).andReturn(10).atLeastOnce();

        PowerMock.replayAll();

    }

    @Test
    public void testtry() throws Exception {
        // After try2() returns 10 recursively inside my try() method,
        // I expect result to be 11
        /* Test */
        Integer result = Trial.try1(1);

        /* Asserts */
        PowerMock.verifyAll();
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(11), result);

    }
}
```